# How can I read a file and store each sentence in an arrayList using Scanner only?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have been having a lot of trouble doing this and due to this being an assignment, I can't post my whole code. I have been able to successfully store each word into an `ArrayList` like the assignment requires, but I really need to store each sentence into an `ArrayList`, but I am having a lot of difficulty doing so.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class WordLookUp {
    private String[] mostWords;
    private String line;
    private List<String> original;
    private List<String> mostOccur = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private String token;
    private List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String sToken;
    private Scanner reader2;
    private String[] ss;

    public WordLookUp(String file) throws Exception {
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(file));){
            this.original = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.sToken = null;

            while (reader.hasNext()) { //reads file and stores it in string
                this.token = reader.next();
                this.original.add(this.token); //adds it to my arrayList
                findMostOccurringWords(this.token);
                this.sToken = reader.nextLine(); //how can I make this read and store sentences only
                this.sentences.add(this.sToken);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

As you see, I have used `reader.nextLine()` but of course this is storing lines in the file only. I tested this out by printing it:

```
public void print() {
    for (String s : this.sentences) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

And this confirms this. However, I have not been able to find out how to split an `ArrayList` (I don't think you can) or how I can simply put each sentence into an index of the sentences `ArrayList`. I can't use any built in libraries like `Collections` or `Array`, I would have to manually figure out how I can store each sentence in the `ArrayList`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a bit off. When you read `next()` and then `nextLine()`, `nextLine()` won't include what was read with `next()` so you'll be skipping a word every iteration. Try this:

-Read a line using the `useDelimiter();` method to read until a period, exlamation mark, or question mark (The end of a sentence)

Example of using a `.` as a delimiter:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner("Hello. This is a string. It has multiple senteces").useDelimiter("\\.");
while(in.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(in.next());
}
```

-Add the sentence to the sentence `ArrayList()`

-Split the sentence into seperate words and add them to the words `ArrayList()`

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I have never heard of useDelimeter, but it is not letting me do this: this.sToken = reader.useDelimeter("."); It says "can not convert form Scanner to string. I am not really keen on creating a new Scanner. I have used the two different versions of it, but it still is not letting me store it into this.sToken. Any ideas ?

Comment: I then did this: this.sToken = reader.useDelimiter(".").next(); 
   this.sentences.add(this.sToken); but now it says an error java.util.Scanner.throwFor unknown source

Comment: @SaturnsBelt `useDelimeter ` is for the `Scanner` object. (`reader.useDelimeter("\\.");`)

Comment: @SaturnsBelt I edited my answer to include an example

Answer (score 0):

Next time give us more details about your assignment so we dont have to guess it :)

Anyhow, use the following construct to read each sentence:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter("\."); 
while (sc.hasNext()) {
     // we will hold your sentence in the s variable
     Sting s = sc.next();
     // here you add the string to your sentence array
     // or better be conscious about your memory usage 
     // and do the processing right away.
     processSentence(s);
}
```

From your code snippet seems like you need to collect statistics about your word count and most popular word. `HashMap<String, Integer>` would be good structure for that.

```
void processSentence(String s) {
    Scanner ws = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter(" "); 
    while (ws.hasNext()) {
        Sting w = ws.next();
        // I assume you have this.wordCounters initialized as HashMap<String,Integer>();
        Integer c = this.wordCounters.get(w);
        if (c==null) { c=0; }
        c = c+1;
        this.wordCounters.put(w, c);
    }
}
```